# How do I get the data of other markets using Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I am currently learning how to use Python for finance.

I know how to get the data of various American companies like apple using the code:

```
import pandas_datareader.data as web
import datetime

start = datetime.datetime(2010, 1, 1)
end = datetime.datetime(2013, 1, 27)

f = web.DataReader("AAPL", 'google', start, end)
```

But if I use a company from another country like India(Eg:*BHARTIARTL*) it throws an error.

> Unable to read URL: http://www.google.com/finance/historical?startdate=Jan+01%2C+2010&enddate=Jan+27%2C+2013&q=BHARTIARTL&output=csv

How can I get the data from these companies?

Comment: Have a look at https://pypi.python.org/pypi/yahoo-finance/1.1.4, it might help

Answer (score 0):

datareader module in pandas connects with google finance which provides historical data on NYSE. You have a couple of options.

1. Write your own module in pandas/python that works with Indian exchanges
2. Use packages created by other developers for retrieving market data. I find this one might serve your purpose.
   (https://github.com/swapniljariwala/nsepy)
3. There are quite a few companies in India that provide APIs to access market data. But they are not usually free to use.